# Using WordPress core pop-up comment function, doesn't popup, maybe an elementor issue

Tags: comments

I'm trying to get the WordPress core comment popup function to work, but no luck so far..

I've been following this guide: https://firstsiteguide.com/open-wordpress-comments-popup/

But since I'm using elementor pro in WordPress,  there are some issues with changing the correct PHP files, but I have inserted the php code at the corresponding places.

This is the first code:

```
<?PHP
comments_popup_script(500, 600);
?>
```

This is the "call the popup script" function:

```
<?PHP
comments_popup_link( 'No comments', '1 comment', '% comments', 'btn btn-primary', 'Comments Disabled');
?>
```

This will display:
5 comments
And if I press the text it only adds #comment after the url, but no popup..

Now, as I wrote before, i can't guarantee that the first script is called, and I'm a newbie at this..

Does anybody know anything about this?

Comment: Not every guide on the internet has to be followed, and really in case of problem with the guide you should ask the author. Frankly I am amazed that anyone still knows that this kind of functionality exists, and in the (too many) years I was using WordPress I have **never** seen anyone using it, so you might have a rough ride if you are going to try to use it in any productive way.

Comment: Since I'm using fixed background picture with no repeat, I need the pop-up or else it would look ugly when the users scroll down below the background picture..

Comment: What I am trying to suggest (done badly since I was truly surprised anyone knows about it, and shocked that anyone in 2017 still suggest to change core files) that some modern JS to open the comment section in a popup will look much better than trying to adjust old functionality no one likely tried to test and maintain for years.

Comment: @markkaplun ok, well since I'm a newbie I was looking for the easiest way to implant it. I've also searched for a plugin that could solve this, but no luck yet. You don't have any suggestions?